# Sometimes images are not loaded in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dojo

I am using an Iframe to load an external page. The page has an image which sometimes loads but most time does not (worse in IE10 and 11). If the url is loaded directly into the browser without an Iframe it always loads, but not with the Iframe. Our application has an Iframe portlet that will call such an HTML file or one with a redirect. We cannot load the url directly into our Iframe because Dojo has a problem with the url parameter which is not valid encoding. The url creates a new image file every time it is executed and those are deleted at some point. Is this a known issue with Iframes? Is there a workaround without JQuery?

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame"
    src="http://www.gomeznetworks.com/charting/publicForm.asp?crypt=%7F%B3%AC%B2%C8%B2%96%C6%C1sc%7D%7Fj%85qe%B4%A3%9C%AB%B4%8E%9C%8Fe%90Tzc%96%8Fp"
    height="99%"
    width="100%"
    marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0"
>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the issue appears to be with the url parameters not being correctly encoded.. which is causing the JS to fail.. which in turn is stopping the image from being generated.. i think chrome and safari must be a little more lenient with their url encoding

Comment: Actually, the url parameter looks like url encoding , but it is not. It is proprietary Gomez encoding. You are correct about Dojo failing on trying to decode this, but with my simple HTML I do in fact get an image returned sometimes. The problem is only with the Iframe. If I put the url directly into the browser's location entry then everything is always returned successfully.

Comment: The problem was that an Iframe is apparently dealt with by the browser security in the same way as an external link. These links made use of cookies. Browsers set to block cookies had the problem. Once we allowed cookies for this site the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that an Iframe is apparently dealt with by the browser security in the same way as an external link. These links made use of cookies. Browsers set to block cookies had the problem. Once we allowed cookies for this site the problem was fixed.